# Google maps Custom info window not showing properly on iphone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps

I am making Uber like application. when user select pick up and destination address, then i draw route between these two addresses.

I have two separate info windows  for both Source address and destination address.

This is working fine on my iphone 7 pluse and iphone 6s. But when i try to draw route on iPhone x, the route is drawn successfully but one of the info window is always incorrect.

I have tried every solution. I checked constraints too. everything is fine.

```
//Destination info window

let infoWindow1 = DestinationInfoWindow.instanceFromNib() as! DestinationInfoWindow
dest.iconView = infoWindow1
infoWindow1.DestinationLabel.text = locationStringwithDetail
infoWindow1.lblRemainingDistance.text = String(self.estimatedDistance.rounded(toPlaces: 1))
self.destinationName = locationStringwithDetail
self.destinationCoordinate = destinationCoordinate

dest.zIndex = 0
dest.position = destinationCoordinate
dest.map = self.mapView

// Source info window
let infoWindow = MapMarkerWindow.instanceFromNib() as! MapMarkerWindow
infoWindow.remaingDriverTimelbl.pushTransition(0.4)
if self.estimatedITime != 0 && self.estimatedITime < 30*60 {
    var inMinuts:Int = self.estimatedITime/60
    if inMinuts == 0{
        inMinuts = 1
    };infoWindow.remaingDriverTimelbl.text = "\(inMinuts)"
} else { infoWindow.remaingDriverTimelbl.text = "~" }

self.sourceName = locationName
self.sourceAdress = locationAdress
mySrc.iconView = infoWindow
mySrc.zIndex = 1
infoWindow.sourceTitle.text = locationStringwithDetail
mySrc.position = sourceCoordinate
mySrc.map = self.mapView
```

## There is no error. the issue is only on `iPhone X` device and simulator.

[image]

## Here is screen shot for `iPhone 7+`:

[image]

[Here is xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9DpX.jpg)

Comment: zeeshan haider can you please attach some snapshot of your example window and what you are getting right now?

Comment: yes i have added two images one from iphone x and other from iphone 7 plus

Comment: can you just remove transition and give it a try?

Comment: i did but not worked

Comment: let infoWindow = MapMarkerWindow.instanceFromNib() as! MapMarkerWindow
try setting frame programmatically after initilization,

Comment: i am assuming you have implemented constraints on XIB file

Comment: to do this you may do infoWindow.frame = infoWindow1.frame right after this let infoWindow = MapMarkerWindow.instanceFromNib() as! MapMarkerWindow

Comment: @AbuUlHassan yes i have implemented constraints on XIB file. should i remove them?

Comment: i tried both suggestions but did not worked.

Comment: show me xib picture of XIB with constrains .

Comment: i have added screen shot of xib file

Comment: everthing looking fine, now can you try by commenting   statements where you are assigning text.

Comment: sorry but now i need its a hit and try also try to use zIndex=0 instead of 1.

Comment: it did not fixed issue